# Index was outside the bounds of the array VB .NET

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

I am getting the following error "Index was outside the bounds of the array" whenever I type a Password whit the following System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
Any idea on what is wrong here?

```
    If Membership.ValidateUser(Login1.UserName, Login1.Password)                                          Then
        'Has the password expired? 
        Dim usrInfo As MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser(Login1.UserName)
        Dim roles As String() = System.Web.Security.Roles.GetRolesForUser(usrInfo.UserName.ToString())
        If roles(0).Equals("User") Then
            Dim daysSincePwdChange As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.Subtract(usrInfo.LastPasswordChangedDate).TotalDays)
            If daysSincePwdChange > SecurityUtils.DefaultPasswordExpiryInDays Then
                'Password expired, send user to change password 
                'MsgBox("expire passwd")
```

Answer (score 0):

System.Web.Security.Roles.GetRolesForUser isn't returning any results for the value passed to it, so your array is empty.
When you look for the first value in your array with 
If roles(0).Equals("User")...
it is throwing the error.

You can handle the error by adding something like

```
If NOT roles.getLength() = 0 Then
If roles(0).Equals("User") Then
            Dim daysSincePwdChange...
```

Or use Try/Catch for error handling.